Why does ElasticAPM crash Electron application with EBADF while accessing filesystem on Windows?
I use elastic-apm-node to instrument an Electron app. I initialize it with default options:
import * as apm from 'elastic-apm-node';

apm.start({
//... service name, token and so on
})

It is part of a package that is installed as a dependency and ran on the electron app's main process. Another part of that package is accessing the filesystem using electron-store which results in the following error (only on Windows):
EBADF: bad file descriptor, write

I am certain that it's the APM that started to cause that issue. It seems like somehow starting the agent prevents electron-store from accessing the filesystem. I'm not sure however, what is this elastic-apm-node doing to do so. Is it because it tries to instrument the code that is doing I/O operations and thus blocks the write access?
